# Error inflating class fragment when using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement google maps in my android app. I followed [this](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) guide but im getting "Error inflating class fragment", i can't figure out what is wrong.

My layout file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();    
    }    
}
```

Manifest (replaced my real api key with "my_api_key"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_api_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?  Do you have Google Play Services integrated in your project?

Comment: Im using eclipse and I added Google Play Services to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies, I just figured out what I was doing wrong. I enabled usb data transfer to my pc in my phone, that's why application was crashing. Can't belive I made such a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SupportMapFragment map =(SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map.getMapAsync(this);
```

Let MainActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback.
we get the map object through callback when map is ready

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap; 
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have implemented google maps api v2 in my app

try this code

xml file

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

class file

```
//extends activity and implements onMapReady
public class map_activity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myfile_layout);
}

 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //do everything with the map
    //change the map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current locati
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(23.634501, -102.552784);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
}
```

If this help you, don't forget to make this answer as correct...